# Can i get another object from class method?

Tags: objective-c

So, i want to get NSDictionary from class method, i think it will be like this:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [SomeClass parseJSONAndGetDictionary];
```

Can someone explain me how i can make it?

Comment: What you did above is correct. You can get a class property or call a class function like: `[ClassName propertyName]` or `[ClassName functionName:parameters]`. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @ozgur i want to make class that download me data from Flickr API, parse data and return me NSDictioanry. And the main problem that i don't understand how i can return from class method the dictionary. +(NSDictionary *)methodName; i hope there is some syntax for my try, but i can't find it in documentation(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in you `.h` file of your `SomeClass` declare method like,

```
  + (NSDictionary*)aClassMethod;
```

and in your `.m` file of your `SomeClass` implement it like it will return `NSDictionary` something like,

```
  + (NSDictionary*)population{ 

       // get desired dictionary here and return it

      return dictionary ;
  }
```

the you can got dictionary from any class like,

```
 NSDictionary *dictionary = [SomeClass parseJSONAndGetDictionary];
```

by implementing `SomeClass.h` file in that class.